# How to make Random.Range() step by a certain amount?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this is a very simple question, but I couldn't find out how to solve it. Lets say I have this line:

```
Random.Range(2,4);
```

I want this to generate not only whole numbers but also halves. What I mean is the step should be 0.5. I want it to choose randomly from the following only:
2, 2.5, 3, 3.5
I don't want any other decimal numbers. Can somebody help?

Comment: Random.Range(4, 8) * 0.5f

Comment: ...or `new double[] {2, 2.5, 3, 3.5}[Random.Range(0, 4)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple solution for your specific case.

```
var randomNumber = ((float)Random.Range(4, 8)) * 0.5f;
```

You can also extend the method to work with different values.

```
public float GetRandomFloat(int min, int max, float value = 0.5f)
{
    int multipliedMin = (int) (max / value);
    int multipliedMax = (int) (max / value);

    return ((float) Random.Range(multipliedMin, multipliedMax)) * value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

System.Random class doesn't have the feature you need natively , you can make your own method or extension for it

method

```
// use only one instance of System.Random to avoid getting duplicates
  static System.Random ra = new Random();
  static double GenRnadNum(int min,int max,double step)
        {
           //  calc the max-min and round down
            int n = (int)((max - min) / step);
            int r=  ra.Next(0, n);
            return min + r * step;
        }
```

usage example `dd.Add(GenRnadNum(5, 20, 0.7));`

i see many people doing it by dividing the max and min by the step (max/step,min/step)
and then multiplying the result random by the step (randomRestul*step)
but this will generate wrong results for example min=2,max=4,step=0.3 can give you 2.4 with that algorithm (2/0.3=6.66-->7 ,random result=8, 8*0.3=2.4)